# Q: How to form LINQ query to access nested attributes within class to display on Blazor WASM application

Tags: c#, .net, linq, graphql, blazor

My apologies for the vast amount of code, but it is necessary for the context of the problem. I am faced with an interesting dilemma that I have not been able to solve. I am trying to access information from model called Repository. Repository contains nested classes and lists, and looks like this:

```
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public PinnedItems PinnedItems { get; set; }
    }
    public class PinnedItems
    {
        public List<Nodes> Nodes { get; set; }
    }
    public class Nodes
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public RepositoryTopics RepositoryTopics { get; set; }
    }
    public class RepositoryTopics
    {
        public List<TopicNodes> Nodes { get; set; }
    }
    public class TopicNodes
    {
        public Topic Topic { get; set; }

    }
    public class Topic
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }    
    }
```

I have the following method within a web api controller. It is responsible for grabbing my github repositories using graphql. This method looks like this:

```
        {
            var request = new GraphQLHttpRequest
            {
                Query = @"query($username: String!){
  user(login: $username) {
        pinnedItems(first: 6, types: REPOSITORY) {
      nodes {
        ... on Repository {
          name
          description
          url
          repositoryTopics(first:6){
            nodes{
              topic{
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
",

                Variables = new
                {
                    username = _configuration.GetSection("GithubUserName").Value
                }
            };
            var graphQlResponse = await CreateClient().SendQueryAsync<Repository>(request);
            var repo = new Repository
            {
                User = graphQlResponse.Data.User
        
            };
            return Ok(repo);
        }
```

repo is of type Repository.
This is an example piece of JSON that comes back from testing the controller in swagger.

```
    "pinnedItems": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "name": "personal-website",
          "description": "My personal website",
          "url": "https://github.com/personal-website",
          "repositoryTopics": {
            "nodes": [
              {
                "topic": {
                  "name": "blazor-webassembly"
                }
              },
              {
                "topic": {
                  "name": "web-api"
                }
              },
              {
                "topic": {
                  "name": "contentful-api"
                }
              },
              {
                "topic": {
                  "name": "contentful"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

I am accessing the code in my blazor component with the following:

```
    Repository SoftwareRepos = new Repository();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
        SoftwareRepos = await graphQLquery.GetRepositories();
    }
}
```

And some example code such as this gets me the list of projects as a name.

```
@foreach(var name in SoftwareRepos.User.PinnedItems.Nodes.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray())
        {
            @name
        }
PRINTS OUT: name, name, name, name
```

Ideally I would want something that looks like this:

`Project One, Description, URL, html, css, react, javascript (a list of tags)`

I am having trouble trying to construct LINQ queries to access this nested information (particularly repositoryTopic -> TopicNodes -> Nodes -> Topics -> Name.
I am seeking advice on how to approach this situation, or maybe some alternative solutions to what I am doing as I suspect I am a little out of my depth here. I am using graphql.client to send and retrieve information from github.

Answer (score 0):

first thing to do is to deserialize that JSON into a class structure that it represents.

```
 public class GitResponse{
      public Node[] PinnedItems {get;set;}
 }
 public class Node{
     public string Name {get;set};
     public string Description {get;set;}
     ....
 }
```

etc. Once this is done the rest is easy , you just walk that tree

deserialize with

```
   System.Text.Json.Serailizer.Deserialize<GitResponse>(json);
```

Comment: Hi pm, it is my understanding that the deserialisation is performed with CreateClient().SendQueryAsync<Repository>(request); I will investigate this and see what I come up with. Ta

Comment: @tudor14 I dont know graphql library so maybe it does, I was just going off the json you said was returned to you. Maybe I misread your question